# Código retorna undefined quando executado

Tags: javascript

Amigos, estou aprendendo a programar e comecei por JavaScript.

Estou com dificuldades. Meu código não está retornando o valor da função `calcIrpf()`.

O código não está completo. O objetivo é calcular o salário líquido de acordo com a CLT. Faltam mais etapas. Porém estou bloqueado no retorno da função.

```js
<meta charset="utf-8">
<h1>Cálculo de Salário</h1>
<p><br>Informe seu salário</p>
<input/>
<button>Calcular</button>


<script>
 var input = document.querySelector("input");
 input.focus();

 function calcIrpf(){

  var salario = input.value;
  var alIrpf = [0.075, 0.15, 0.225, 0.275];
  var parcDedut = [142.8, 354.8, 636.13, 869.36];;
  
  if (salario <= 1903.98){
   var valIrpf = 0;
  }else{
   if (salario >1903.98 && salario <=2826.65) {
    valIrpf = (salario*alIrpf[0])-parcDedut[0];
   }else{
    if (salario > 2826.65 && salario <= 3751.05) {
     valIrpf = (salario*alIrpf[1])-parcDedut[1];
    }else{
     if(salario > 3751.05 && salario <= 4664.68){
      valIrpf = (salario*alIrpf[2])-parcDedut[2];
     }else{
      if(salario < 4664.68){
       valIrpf = (salario*alIrpf[3])-parcDedut[3];
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

  return valIrpf;
 }

 function mostra(){
  document.write("<br>O valor de IRPF descontado é: R$"+calcIrpf());
 }

 var button = document.querySelector("button");
 button.onclick = mostra;

</script>
```

Comment: Faltou colocar na pergunta o principal: o problema.

Comment: falta ; em return valIrpf

Comment: Amadeu Antunes -> Corrigi o ; porém não solucionou.

Comment: Sam -> Corrigi a pergunta

Comment: Nesse último if, o sinal deveria ser maior e não menor: `if(salario < 4664.68){`... seria `if(salario > 4664.68){`

Answer (score 2):

No último `if`, o sinal deveria ser *maior que* (`>`):

```
if (salario > 4664.68){
            ↑
```

Agora, é preciso ajustar o escopo da variável `valIrpf` dentro da função. No primeiro `if`, você declarou a variável com `var` e nos outros sem o `var`, ou seja, a variável só terá escopo na função no primeiro `if`, nos outros terá escopo global (poderá ser acessada fora da função).

Antes dos `if`'s declare a variável com o valor `0`. Se nenhuma condição for atendida, o valor da variável será `0`. Também, em vez de usar vários `if`'s aninhados, use `else if` para verificar condições variadas.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.focus();

function calcIrpf(){

   var salario = input.value;
   var alIrpf = [0.075, 0.15, 0.225, 0.275];
   var parcDedut = [142.8, 354.8, 636.13, 869.36];
   var valIrpf = 0; // valores iguais ou abaixo de 1903.98
   
   if (salario > 1903.98 && salario <= 2826.65){
      valIrpf = (salario*alIrpf[0])-parcDedut[0];
   }else if (salario > 2826.65 && salario <= 3751.05){
      valIrpf = (salario*alIrpf[1])-parcDedut[1];
   }else if (salario > 3751.05 && salario <= 4664.68){
      valIrpf = (salario*alIrpf[2])-parcDedut[2];
   }else if (salario > 4664.68){
      valIrpf = (salario*alIrpf[3])-parcDedut[3];
   }

   return valIrpf;
}

function mostra(){
   document.write("<br>O valor de IRPF descontado é: R$"+calcIrpf());
}

var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.onclick = mostra;
```

```html
<h1>Cálculo de Salário</h1>
<p><br>Informe seu salário</p>
<input/>
<button>Calcular</button>
```

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda! É um erro bobo, mas quando estamos a muito tempo olhando a mesma coisa... nem percebemos.